# Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ has infinite measure, and $f\in L^1(E)$, Is this true that $f \in L^{\infty}(E)$ necessarily?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ has infinite measure, and $f\in L^1(E)$,

Is this true that $f \in L^{\infty}(E)$ necessarily ?

I could not find a counterexample so far and it is a useful fact if it is true(sometimes to be able to use Holder's inequality)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Take $E=\Bbb R^*_+$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ on $(1,+\infty)$

Comment: In fact, $f$ need not be essentially bounded on any interval. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86310/prove-series-is-unbounded-on-any-interval) for an idea on how to construct such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a function defined on $[1/(n+1),1/n]$ as $\sqrt{n}$ on the interval $[0,1]$, and zero otherwise.

Comment: E has "infinite" measure

Comment: Use your imagination on how to trivially fill up the definition on the reals.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, taking 
$$f(x):=\sum_{j=1}^\infty2^{-j}\frac 1{\sqrt{|x-r_j|}},$$
where $(r_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is an enumeration of rationals, we can see that

- $f$ is integrable;
- if $I\subset (0,1)$ is an interval, then $f$ is unbounded on $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $E=(0,\infty)$ and let
$$f=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & x\in [0,1]\\ 0&\mathrm{o.w.}\end{cases}$$
Then $f\in L^1(E)$, but not in $L^\infty(E)$.