# Construction of an Integrable Function with Unboundedness Conditions

Tags: measure-theory

Construct a function $f\geq 0$ s.t. $f$ is unbounded in every interval, but $\int f dx<\infty$.

Comment: Hint: Try to construct a function that differs from zero only on the rationals.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86310/prove-series-is-unbounded-on-any-interval).

Answer (score 0):

Start with the function $$f(x)\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } x\in\mathbb Q\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Which is integrable as its integral equals $0$. Then just push the function even higher on the rationals, for example, for each rational number $p/q$, where $GCD(p,q)=1$, look at the function $g(p/q) = p$.